# How much view-agnostic is a ViewModel supposed to be in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, javafx, design-patterns, mvvm

Let's imagine a very simple UI, where there's a list of checkboxes. When you click on any of them:

1) if it's not selected, it should create a workspace with this checkbox name (and more logic then is available in that workspace, but that's irrelevant to the question). The checkbox naturally then becomes selected;

2) If it's already selected, it should turn unselected and should destroy the associated workspace.

The straightaway form of implementing this is to have the `View` look at the state of the clicked checkbox and depending on being already selected or not do a `viewModel.createWorkpace()` or `viewModel.destroyWorkspace()`. But then that means that this logic is in the `View` -- I get the impression it'd be better to have it in the `ViewModel`.

I've read that the `ViewModel` for diverse reasons should not know the `View`. But one thing is not having a physical dependency to the `View` (an object reference, for instance) and another completely different is not even being aware that the `View` may have checkboxes, as in this example.

It gives me the impression that actually there's really not big of a point in making the `View` and `ViewModel` that much different, and in fact, the closer the `ViewModel` is to the `View`, the easier it is to bind data between the `View` and `ViewModel`.

How should I deal with this situation and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to decouple the view and viewmodel.
You should be able to instantiate the viewmodel separately.
The primary reason for this is not some vague neatness or something. 
The primary reason is so you can easily exercise tests on your code by instantiating a discrete class.

The view should do view things which are related to displaying data and allowing the user to interact.
The viewmodel should have the code that acts on those interactions and presents data to the view.
This does not mean the view should have no code at all.
If there is code, however, it should be view specific.
It's a good idea to use re-usable code such as behaviours.
Because then you can manually test these and prove they work. Then re-use your proven code.
Similarly with converters, validators etc.

All code.

All used in views.

I suppose it is theoretically possible to write an app which has no converters or validators or behaviours. I've never seen a serious business app didn't have all three though.

It is less important that the view knows nothing about the viewmodel than the reverse.
You're not going to instantiate the view to exercise tests unless you also have a viewmodel instantiated for it.
That doesn't mean you should just bung all your code into code behind though.

Why is that exactly?
Because the god of MVVM will strike you down with his lightning bolts?
Nope.
Because this will make future development easier?
Well it might, but not usually so much you'd notice.

Why then?
Because instantiating a view with it's controls is very slow.
They unavoidably have a lot of dependencies you can't mock.
It is likely to depend on resource in the application, so you'd have to instantiate an application and merge resource dictionaries.
Views often depend on swathes of libraries, pictures, usercontrols etc etc.
None of which you can mock.
So you need everything.
By the time you automate instantiating everything in some test runner and iron out clicking on buttons etc...
Your head will be hurting and you'll find those 2000 test you're theoretically wanting to run in a couple of seconds every 10 minutes take much longer than that couple of seconds.
You can't do "proper" TDD if you instantiate views in tests.

To answer your workspace checkbox question.
It depends on what a workspace is really.

A common pattern would be to initiate code in the setter of a viewmodel property bound to the ischecked property of each checkbox.
That might be in a viewmodel presented per checkbox which had the name of the workspace, it's type or whatever is required to do it's check-uncheck stuff.
Each would hold some sort of reference to these things it's creating so it can dispose them or whatever when that ischecked value becomes false.